# Script loading order in JS/CSS (with gulp as build system)

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, headjs

I have an HTML file, testLoader.html:

```
<head>
    <style>
    .loader {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 9999;
        background: url('optier-spinner.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat #ccc;
    }
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="head.load.js"></script>
```

etc.

My goal is to have a "loading" image (animated GIF) while JS scripts are loading.
Problem is the image in the `url()` tag in the `<style>` section is fetched only after JS files are loaded, so not effect for the animation.

Network diagram of loading:
[image]

As you can see, the scripts are loaded and only after them the GIF image.
I tried using script loaders like [head.js](http://headjs.com/) and it works, but I use gulp and the JS files of the project are injected during the build process (and the files change from dev to production), so script loader is not an option as far as I know.

How can I make the image to load and be presented while the other files are loaded?

Comment: please mark an answer as accepted if it solves your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that happens is because you load both the `css` and `javascript` inside the document `<head>`. `<script>`-tags are blocking, meaning the browser waits until they have finished downloading and parsing, before it continues to render the page.

Images defined in css will only be downloaded when the selector is rendered, which will be after the scripts are loaded. This is way the gif loads last.

Move all `<script>`-tags just before the closing `</body>`-tag to make sure they don't block the browser and are executed last.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the laoding gif in the HTML, then in your js script something like this:

```
    $(window).load(function() {    
        $("#gif_id").fadeOut("slow");    
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // other code
    });
```

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have
>   been completely loaded

So after all the scripts are loaded you will remove the gif icon.